# HTML5 Form Pattern for word count vs character count

Tags: regex, html

I'm using HTML5 form validation on the frontend to provide users with some feedback when they exceed a character limit in an input.

```
<input id="description" placeholder="description" required="required" type="text" pattern=".{3,500}">
```

This, with some CSS, will let me tell the user if they have not entered between 3 and 500 characters.

How could I actually set the pattern to match the number of "words" instead of characters .e.g. minimum of one word and max of 50 words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work, the first clause `(\w+\W+){0,49}` will match between 0-49 words (of one or more characters) followed by one or more whitespaces.  The second part `\w+\W*` will match one more word with optional whitespace following.

```html
<form>
  <input id="description" placeholder="description" required="required" type="text" pattern="(\w+\W+){0,49}\w+\W*">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is good and qualifies as correct. However, I did notice that this approach tripped up on commas for some reason. This: `^\s*(\S+\s+){0,49}\S*$` did the trick for me.